# Reverse engineering using netbeans7.3

Tags: php, symfony, uml, netbeans-7

I need to make uml  diagram of my project using reverese engineering. How could I do it in NetBeans 7.3?
i'm working with symfony2 
thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Any UML tool with reverse engineering will do.

I don't know about NetBeans, but IntelliJ can generate class diagrams for you.  It'll even generate sequence diagrams if you run a class.

You're likely to be disappointed with the results unless it's a small, academic project.  Reverse engineering a large project into UML only results in dense diagrams that are impossible to read and provide little or no insight whatsoever.